# Alternative to Alt-Tab on Openbox?

Tags: linux, openbox

I get RSI from using Alt-Tab.

1) Any easier app or way to switch tasks?

2) Can I map it to a single key ?

I use Openbox as my Desktop Environment and I don't use panels much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openbox is fully configurable. You can map any key (like <kbd>Super</kbd>) or key combo (Like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) to any action (Also works to launch apps, terminal commands...).

#### With obkey

Install [obkey](https://code.google.com/p/obkey/) and launch it to set your mapping.

#### Manually

Edit or create the `~/.config/rc.xml` file.

If you're on lubuntu or other distro, this may be called `lubunturc.xml` or differently.

Search for `A-Tab` in it and replace it by your keybinding. You can find simple and complete doc about keybindings (for special characters...) here : openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings, and you have a list of available actions to point to here : openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#PreviousWindow.

Answer (score 2):

On openbox the rc.xml file can be found in ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml

There you should have a section:

```
<keybind key="A-Tab">
  <action name="PreviousWindow"/>
</keybind>
```